# How to watch and apply Dom changes in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

On click of button I am creating a `div` with `<li>` which holds images. I am using the following function:

```
<button data-ng-click="createWorkOrder()">Post project</button>
```

Function:

```
$scope.createWorkOrder  = function () {
    //API call to get data
    $scope.myPromise = operationsFactory.readWorkOrders().success(function (response) {
        $scope.workOrdersList = response.result;
    })
};
```

Html:

```
<ul>
    <li dir-paginate="wd in workOrdersList | filter: search.status | filter: search.name | itemsPerPage: 10">
        <a href=" ">
            <h4>{{wd.name}}</h4>
        </a>
        <p>Status: {{wd.status}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The above list is getting created but I need to refresh the page to see it on page. I want it to display automatically as soon as new data is populated from above function

Comment: after the edit, it is now still unclear.  your button says "Post Project" and the function indicates a create action in it's name, but the code for that function seems only to be a read action.  when does the data get sent to the server?

Comment: right, but you are asking about an issue that you aren't really demonstrating here in a reproducible manner.  angular will update the data automatically unless you aren't changing the values on one side or the other, or are doing them in the wrong order.  You aren't showing the entire process end to end, so it's not obvious what step is missing.

Comment: it doesn't matter what the function name is, but based on the names one might assume that `readWorkOrders` is reading the data that is on the server, and you aren't showing where you are adding the new one, before or after this.

Answer (score 0):

I made [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/alF9MpWHapnCsMgmcDlv) trying to reproduce your problem, and it worked without any problem. 
What [@claies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2495283/claies) said above is right, "angular will update the data automatically unless you aren't changing the values on one side or the other".
Are you sure you're updating the data correctly?

As you can see, as soon as the request ends the list is updated. 
If you code still doesn't work try calling `$scope.$apply()` method after your request is finished, it'll update the bindings. [$scope.$apply docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply)

**View:**

```
<ul>
    <li dir-paginate="wd in workOrdersList | filter: search.status | filter: search.name | itemsPerPage: 5">
        <a href="{{wd.url}}">
            <h4>{{wd.name}}</h4>
        </a>
        <p>Status: {{wd.id}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
<dir-pagination-controls></dir-pagination-controls>
```

**Controller**:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    // Just to reproduce the problem
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://api.github.com/repositories'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
       $scope.workOrdersList = response.data;
    }, function errorCallback(response) {

    });
});
```